# How to free memory on web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, asp-classic

i have a web application in jquery and consume ws from a server in asp .net, and the browser show in the request a long time in blocking state, i see this in the console of the browser.

I think, the problem is, the application consume a lot memory.

Thanks for any solution of this problem :)

This is a image of the console

[image]

the times in the request is the problem, i have a long time in the blocking state.

Comment: Use the developer tools of google chrome and figure it out. You didn't post anything useful to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i add the screenshot of the problem.